# How to locate a file whose downloading failed in chrome

Tags: google-chrome

So I was downloading a file in chrome whose downloading is failed at very end. I looked for the file in my downloads folder but it is not there. Please suggest a way to locate that file.

Answer (score 0):

the file should be named with weird name combination, but with .CRDOWNLOAD extension. so look for that file. Chrome cannot resume that, but you can resume it from the firefox. hope this link will help http://www.addictivetips.com/web/resume-a-failed-chrome-download-from-where-it-left-off/